# number of ways to climb up and down stairs in 2n steps

Tags: combinatorics

starting from the 0th (bottom) step, and assuming you have an infinitely long staircase, how would you calculate the possible ways to climb up and down the stairs in 2*n steps so that you end up back on the 0th step?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote U for upstairs and D for downstairs. As initial and final position are same, so there are equal number of U and D, so the no. Of ways should be 2nCn ,but as we cannot go below the 0 step, hence no initial string should contain more D than U. 
Therefore no. Of ways is 2nCn-2nC(n+1)